# How to setup .net in team environment

Tags: c#, winforms, svn

I am developing application as stand alone single system till now . Now i have in need of centralize my work area and developing it as a team ... Any great tips on how to setup the team environment for visual studio 2008 and sql server 2005 . I am not interested in TFS . Thanks in advance ...

Comment: use git, it if you are working disconnected or remotely it is much better

Comment: I think it depends on whether your team works on the same LAN/WAN or is disconnected and works over the internet.

Comment: It also depends what he does. SOmetimes a server is a lot more efficient ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualSVN is a very good choice. It works on Windows, is very reliable, and you can set up users with permissions to different repositories and even folders. It it made to work seamlessly with Visual Studio.

http://www.visualsvn.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you implying that you haven't been using source control when working by yourself?  I recommend against that.  Even if you're the only developer on the project, *always* use source control.

Aside from that, I second @IanNorton's recommendation to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) for source control.  [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) is another good option, though less popular.  [Subversion](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is also a good option.  All of these have very similar [shell-integrated](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) [Windows](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) [clients](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

I'd also recommend something like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration builds.  Ideally you'll want automated builds and test runners to happen on every check-in so that you know immediately if there's a problem with the code, and something like a nightly build-and-deploy to a shared environment (including tearing down and re-building the test data).

Comment: -1. For 90% of the people working on rojects, any of the free hosting thigns are illegal to use - see, company code on a public hosting website is a NONONONONO. And most work is not open source.

Comment: @TomTom: Fair enough.  The options are _available_ nonetheless, one should just check with the licensing and whatnot.  But I see your point, I'll remove those links.

Comment: The main point is - given noo implication of open source, it is not exactly a good reference. Most people overlook that most source just is not open at all ;)

Comment: @TomTom: Honestly, I often overlook that even _some_ source _is_ open.  I don't work on open-source much at all.  I do use BitBucket for free private repos for non-open-source but at the same time non-commercial (at least for now) projects, though.  It seem innocuous enough to the task.  It's a good point regardless... When looking at any tools or services, pay close attention to licensing and terms of service with regards to one's project.

Answer (score -2):

> I am not interested in TFS .

Stupid- especialyl beacuse you make obvious why using TFS would be good for you.

Let's get this straight - TFS does 2 things that are important for you:

- Source control.
- WOrk item tracking, including planning (and soon 2011 has full support for SCRUM)
- Continous integration.
  If you get bigger, add item 4:
- Testing. Not all can be done continous, and TFS Has great supprot with Visual Studio for manual test plans etc.

Most people saying "I do not lik TFS" are the same that are ignorant regarding what TFS really brings. NOt saying all is perfect, but I just finsihed an 18 month proejct where NOT using TFS was the worst stupid decision we made ;)

You need them all to be properly protected - a good methodoliogy (no, sorry, just a source control system does not cut it), continous integration and a system to plan the project and assign tasks.

Things get complicated with a database - I would strongly suggest ugprading to SQL 2012, the new localdb mode is prciceless for continous integration.

Btw., in my last project we lost weeks with fighting SVN issues (mostly at some points the stupid server delivered the wrong version as current - and we had a real fight to make the bad one unstuck ;)

The environment would be:

- A number of servers allwoing virtual machines to be pulled up. Developers may need a couple of them.
- Remember build servers LOVE SSD - for performance ;)

Comment: Hi TomTom , I am not interested in TFS because of it's commercial . Apart from that comparing to others it's a better tool as like you said ...

Comment: YOu know how cheap TFS is for small teams? Like zero ;) TFS Exprss. Plus, brutally speaking, all the rest also gets expensive... Not SVN, but seriously - we lost weeks on that one ;)

Comment: 'weeks' what? 'lost' what? 0_0